# Based on Quine–McCluskey algorithm. Improve Nested loop for performance

Tags: c#

I have a running program. That accepts 1 to 15 variables
The goal of the program was a simplifier. Based on the ***Quine–McCluskey algorithm***

Consider 3 variables

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

I group them by number of 1

```
000

001
010
100

011
101
110

111
```

Then I compare each string from the group to the next group

```
group 1
000

group 2
001
010
100

group 3
011
101
110

group1 -> group2
------------------
    000 -> 001 = 00-
    000 -> 010 = 0-0
    000 -> 100 = -00
------------------
group2 ->group3
--------------------  
    001 -> 011 = 0-1
    001 -> 101 = -01
    001 -> 110 = no output

    010 -> 011 = 01-
    010 -> 101 = no output
    010 -> 110 = -10

    100 -> 011 = no output
    100 -> 101 = 10-
    100 -> 110 = 1-0

---------------------
etc.
```

then group the output again by number of 1 and compare them again until no strings can be compared.

I need to achieve a 15 variable but it take for ever for the program to finish.Any Idea how to speed it up. I was testing it on threading but just a little improvement.

> Number of Strings: 2048 Length of variable: 11 Time: 10 minutes

***Need to Achieved***

> Number of Strings: 32767 Length of variable: 15 Time: cannot be achieved

```
 List<List<string>> ImplicantsByOneFinal = new List<List<string>>();
 List<List<string>> TermsByOne = new List<List<string>>();
```

***is there a way or algorithm to improve this code. it becomes slower on 11 to 15 variables.***

```
bool CombineAndGroup(List<List<string>> ImplicantsByOne)
{ 
            TermsByOne = new List<List<string>>();
            int combined = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < ImplicantsByOne.Count - 1; i++)
            { 
                List<string> termsGrouped = new List<string>();
                for (int j = 0; j < ImplicantsByOne[i].Count; j++)
                { 
                    int combination = 0;
                    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32((ImplicantsByOne[i][j]).Replace('-','0'), 2); 
                        for (int k = 0; k < ImplicantsByOne[i + 1].Count; k++)
                        { 
                            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32((ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k]).Replace('-', '0'), 2);
                            int num3 = num2 - num1;
                            double num4 = Math.Log((double)num3, (double)2); 
                            if (((num4 % 1) == 0) && (num3 > 0) && (Esum(ImplicantsByOne[i][j]) == Esum(ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k])))
                            {  
                                string combinedMinterm = CompareString(ImplicantsByOne[i][j], ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k]); 
                                if (!termsGrouped.Contains(combinedMinterm))
                                {
                                    termsGrouped.Add(combinedMinterm); 
                                }  

                            }
                        }   
                }
                if (termsGrouped.Count > 0)
                {
                    combined += termsGrouped.Count;
                } 
                TermsByOne.Add(termsGrouped);
            }

            return (combined > 0) ? true : false;
        } 

 private int Esum(String binCode)
        {
            binCode = binCode.Replace('1','0');
            binCode = binCode.Replace('-', '1');
            int esum = Convert.ToInt32(binCode, 2);
            return esum;
        }
//Purpose of CompareString is to compare two string and change the unique char to '-'
//like 000 and 001 = 00-
  private string CompareString(string str1, string str2)
        { 
            if (str1 == str2)
            { 
                CountCompareStringLoops++;
                return str1;
            }
            else 
            { 
                if (str1.Length == 1)
                { 
                    return "-";
                }
                int halflength = str1.Length / 2; 
                return CompareString(str1.Substring(0, halflength), str2.Substring(0, halflength)) + CompareString(str1.Substring(halflength), str2.Substring(halflength)); 
            }
        }
```

***Main Program***

```
 MintermsByOne = Loaded with string 000 001 and so on

CombineAndGroup(MintermsByOne);
 ImplicantsByOneFinal = TermsByOne; 
 while (CombineAndGroup(TermsByOne))
 {
        ImplicantsByOneFinal = TermsByOne; 
 }
```

**Output ImplicantsByOneFinal**

Comment: It's good to see you here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write C#, but I want to help. So my code is given in Java.

1. I think `==` is an `O(n)` operation, your `CompareString` is `O(nlgn)` (`n = str1.Length`). Use a simpler and faster `O(n)` way and see if the time decreases:

   ```
   private String CompareString(String str1, String str2) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1.length());
       for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
           if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i))
               sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
           else
               sb.append('-');
       }
       return sb.toString();
   }
   ```
2. Well, I found that there are a lot of `ToInt32`. Calculate the result of all strings in `ImplicantsByOne` at once and use it later. Do the same thing to `Esum`.
3. To check if `num3` is a power of two:

   ```
   private boolean isPowerOfTwo(int x) {
       return (x > 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks .I will try to get the time of CompareString if its faster.Also thanks for the Power of two method :).